# Reshape | values (ValueError) for impute transformation interative imputer fit transform on Bayesian Ridge: ValueError Expected 2D array, got 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, bayesian, imputation

**Problem**
**Updated with new Python code and new Error**

Created new imputer_bayesian_ridge() function not working on 2D requirements  for IterativeImputer to impute training data. Sending in data frame training data, then immediately get data.values for numpy array variable, then reshape(1, -1) this data_array variable. This is a training data with many features, but this effort is only seeking to impute on one single feature.

I pull the numpy array via data[feature].values, then .reshape(-1, 1) to handle a single feature. Not working as it appears that I have something out of sequence.

The feature is simply a single column with many rows, what must I do to send this single column feature as a 2D array for the function interative_imputer_fit.transform()? Perhaps another algorithm works better for single feature column than  RepeatedStratifiedKFold, any suggestions.

```
Ex: single feature column
    data
    data
    data
```

**Shape of train_data**

```
print(train_data.shape)
data_array = train_data.values
data_array = data_array.reshape(-1, 1)
print(data_array.shape)
data_array

(1460, 250)
(365000, 1)
array([[-1.73086488],
       [-0.20803433],
       [-0.20714171],
       ...,
       [-0.11785113],
       [ 0.4676514 ],
       [-0.30599503]])
```

**Code function version 1**

```
def imputer_regressor_bay_ridge(data, y):
    data_array = data.values
    data = data_array.reshape(-1, 1)
    interative_imputer = IterativeImputer(BayesianRidge())
    interative_imputer_fit = interative_imputer.fit(data)
    data_imputed = interative_imputer_fit.transform(data)
    cv = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    scores = cross_val_score(interative_imputer, data, 
                             y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
    
    return scores, data_imputed
```

```
scores, data_imputed = imputer_bay_ridge(train_data)

print('Impute Bay Ridge Mean Accuracy: %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores), std(scores)))
```

**Error**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 169
    167 #train_data, test_data = minmaxscaler(train_data, test_data)  # alternate run for min-max scaler
    168 columns, imputed_df = imputer_regressor(train_data)
--> 169 scores, data_imputed = imputer_regressor_bay_ridge(train_data, test_data)
    171 misTrain = whichColumnsMissing(train_data)
    172 misTest = whichColumnsMissing(test_data)

Cell In[4], line 110, in imputer_regressor_bay_ridge(data, y)
    108 data_imputed = interative_imputer_fit.transform(data)
    109 cv = linear_model.LinearRegression()
--> 110 scores = cross_val_score(interative_imputer, data, 
    111                          y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise')
    113 return scores, data_imputed

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:509, in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    506 # To ensure multimetric format is not supported
    507 scorer = check_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)
--> 509 cv_results = cross_validate(
    510     estimator=estimator,
    511     X=X,
    512     y=y,
    513     groups=groups,
    514     scoring={"score": scorer},
    515     cv=cv,
    516     n_jobs=n_jobs,
    517     verbose=verbose,
    518     fit_params=fit_params,
    519     pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch,
    520     error_score=error_score,
    521 )
    522 return cv_results["test_score"]

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:253, in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
     48 def cross_validate(
     49     estimator,
     50     X,
   (...)
     62     error_score=np.nan,
     63 ):
     64     """Evaluate metric(s) by cross-validation and also record fit/score times.
     65 
     66     Read more in the :ref:`User Guide <multimetric_cross_validation>`.
   (...)
    251 
    252     """
--> 253     X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
    255     cv = check_cv(cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
    257     if callable(scoring):

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:378, in indexable(*iterables)
    359 """Make arrays indexable for cross-validation.
    360 
    361 Checks consistent length, passes through None, and ensures that everything
   (...)
    374     sparse matrix, or dataframe) or `None`.
    375 """
    377 result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 378 check_consistent_length(*result)
    379 return result

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:332, in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    330 uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    331 if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 332     raise ValueError(
    333         "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
    334         % [int(l) for l in lengths]
    335     )

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [365000, 1459]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in the doc, [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) **returns** the new reshaped array.
So you would need to set data_array to its new shape:

```py
data_array = data_array.reshape(-1, 1)
```

I hope this solves the issue!

Comment: good answer. I did catch my code with missing assignment, e.g., data_array = data_array.reshape(-1, 1), as you pointed out, but then I received other errors. I am updating the code and show the new error